# Installing Open Modeller plug-in for QGIS 1.7.4?

Tags: qgis, open-source-gis

How do I install the plug-in of Open Modeller in QGIS 1.7.4?

It is not in the list of plug-in in the spanish version of QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

The plugin likely doesn't work anymore as it is very old — you would need QGIS from 2006, not 1.7.4. [Upstream prefers](http://openmodeller.sourceforge.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=10&Itemid=5) their own application now and it supports exporting. You should therefore be able to use the results for further analysis within QGIS easily.